# Repeat DNS flushing required on El Capitan

Tags: network, macos, dns, internet

I have a mid-2011 Mac Air running OS 10.11.3 and I repeatedly have to run a DNS flush to resolve issues connecting to the internet. This seems to be a recent problem and I don't know what has caused it. Is there a better long term solution than just having to occasionally run a DNS flush?

[edited to correct a typo in OS version number]

Comment: Hi, you could automate it, using automator.  The issue may not be at your computer end, it could be your ISP playing around with DNS servers etc. it depends on how long it has been going on.

Comment: That's a typo, sorry, I meant 10.11.3

Comment: Automating it doesn't really fix the thing that's causing it to be required in the first place, I'd rather try and resolve that issue rather than just find a workaround to mitigate its effects!